# CakePHP 3 format date in select query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3 in my project and I came across of a need to format date for `date_joined` and `date_inactive`field in my report. I can use native select query with date function to format date for the field, but in CakePHP, I am not sure how can I integrate date format in select query.

```
$query = $this->CustomersView->find();
                $query->select(['id','contact_person',''date_joined',
                    'date_inactive','comments','status']);
                $query->toArray();
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried one of the example from CakePHP online [resource](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

```
$date = $query->func()->date_format([
                   'date_joined' => 'literal',
                    '%m-%d-%y' => 'literal'
                ]);

$query->select(['id','contact_person',''date_joined',
                    'date_inactive','comments','status']);
                $query->toArray();
```

But it throws me error below:

```
'Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%m-%d-%y)) AS `datejoined`, CustomersView.date_inactive AS `CustomersView__date_' at line 1'
```

SQL query generated by CakePHP:

```
SELECT CustomersView.id AS `CustomersView__id`,
CustomersView.contact_person AS `CustomersView__contact_person`, 
(date_format(date_joined, %m-%d-%y)) AS `datejoined`, 
CustomersView.date_inactive AS `CustomersView__date_inactive`, 
CustomersView.comments AS `CustomersView__comments`, 
CustomersView.status AS `CustomersView__status` 
FROM customers_view CustomersView
```

Any help is really appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: I think if you're using "literal" you need to put quote marks around the date format, e.g. `'"%m-%d-%y"' => 'literal'` - if you look at the raw SQL you can see that there are no quote marks around the date format string.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed it yesterday that as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the date fields are of an appropriate type in your schema (e.g. `DATETIME`), Cake will return DateTime objects that can be formatted using plain PHP - you don't need to do it in the select.

Example:

```
$query = $this->CustomersView->find();
$query->select(['id','contact_person','date_joined',
  'date_inactive','comments','status']);
$array = $query->toArray();

foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row["date_joined"]->format("dMY");
}
```

Let's say for example that your query only returned one row, and the `date_joined` field here was set to `2015-12-21 23:55:00`. The above code would simply print out `21Dec2015`.

Comment: @ganareth, that will definitely work by but I am looking for more simple way to do the date format instead of doing it in foreach loop. I really appreciate your help. I have added more content to my question. Giving you thumbs-up :)

Comment: Believe me this is the most simple way. You don't need to do a foreach in this way, but really the cleanest way to handle this is to keep the object that the ORM returns and then format the date when you are printing it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem with below code:

```
$query = $this->CustomersView->find();
$date = $query->func()->date_format([
                   'date_joined' => 'literal',
                    "'%m-%d-%y'" => 'literal'
                ]);
$query->select(['id', 'contact_person', 'date_joined' => $date,
                'date_inactive', 'comments', 'status']);
$query->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATE_FORMAT($field, %d-%m-%Y) from MySQL.

**Here it is an example:**

```
$query = $this->CustomersView->find();
                $query->select(['id','contact_person',''DATE_FORMAT(date_joined, "%d-%m-%Y")',
                    'date_inactive','comments','status']);
```

Comment: Not working. Resulting the same Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object